# How to set up a multi-user environment for Azure Functions using queues?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

We have started to use the Queue binding in our Azure functions for longer-running tasks such as sending bulk e-mails and "clean-up" tasks for CosmosDB.  We develop locally with the Functions emulator then commit into VSTS/Azure DevOps which then auto-deploys into our Function App.

It seems as though pretty quickly we're going to have multiple Functions (two local emulators and one cloud function) all listening to the same queue.  We tried disabling locally and renaming locally, but these all seem like awkward workarounds that require too much manual work and have the possibility to push the wrong queue name forward into VSTS.

How do we configure the queue name in the function.json to read an environment variable?  The connection setting in the binding takes the name of an environment variable, but the queue setting wants a string.

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myQueueItem",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "emailer",
      "connection": "STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap variable name with `%` and function can read its value from Application settings on portal and Values in local.settings.json locally.

```
"queueName": "%myqueue%"
```

`connection` property of triggers and bindings is a special case and automatically resolves values as app settings, without percent signs.

See [Binding expressions - app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#binding-expressions---app-settings).